# Create/Update Tag for Intercom.io User in Python

Tags: python-2.7

Unfortunately there's no way to create a user in Intercom.io with a tag, so I'm trying to write some code that will look for an existing tag in Intercom, and if it's there, add a user to that tag, and if it's not, create the tag and add the user to it. I've tried several different variations by looking at the docs for the python-intercom library, but there are conflicting methods ([Intercom.update_tag](http://python-intercom.readthedocs.org/en/latest/api/intercom.html) vs. [Tag.update](https://python-intercom.readthedocs.org/en/latest/)), and nothing has worked yet.

Here's how users are created in Intercom (this works):

```
import time
from members.models import Member
from intercom import Intercom, Tag

Intercom.app_id = settings.INTERCOM_TEST_APP_ID
Intercom.api_key = settings.INTERCOM_TEST_API_KEY

member = Member.objects.get(email="exampleemail@example.com")
Intercom.create_user(
    email=member.email,
    user_id=member.email,
    name="%s %s" % (member.first_name, member.last_name),
    created_at=int(time.time()),
    city_name=member.city,
    last_seen_ip=member.last_ip,
 )
```

Here's what I currently have to look for and create or update tags, which triggers no errors, but doesn't successfully tag the user:

```
tag = Intercom.get_tag(name=member.referral_code)
if tag['id'] != None:
    Intercom.update_tag(member.referral_code, "tag", user_ids=[member.pk])
else:
    Intercom.create_tag(tag, "tag", user_ids=[member.pk])
```

I've also tried variations of the following, but it gets the error "descriptor 'update' requires a 'dict' object but received a 'unicode':

```
if Tag.find_by_name(member.referral_code) != 0:
    Tag.update(member.referral_code, "tag", user_ids=[member.pk])
else: 
    Tag.create(member.referral_code, "tag", user_ids=[member.pk])
```

What do I need to change to get tagging to work?

Answer (score 3):

My name's Jeff, I'm one of the customer success engineers at Intercom. Unfortunately the intercom-python library is still using our deprecated V1 API which is likely causing some of the confusion here. Until that library updates to use our newer [REST API](http://doc.intercom.io/api/) I would suggest that you use the python `requests` library and call our API directly. I've got minimal python experience but something like this should get you started on the right track.

```
import requests
from requests.auth import HTTPBasicAuth
import json

tags_url = 'https://api.intercom.io/tags'
app_id = 'YOUR_APP_ID'
api_key = 'YOUR_API_KEY'
headers = {'content-type': 'application/json', 'Accept': 'application/json'}

tag_name = 'My sweet tag'

# Get tags to then loop through
list_tag_response_as_json = requests.get(tags_url, auth=(app_id, api_key), headers=headers).json()

tag_names = [tag['name'] for tag in list_tag_response_as_json['tags']]

if tag_name not in tag_names
    # Create a tag
    tag_response = requests.post(tags_url, auth=(app_id, api_key), headers=headers, data={'name': tag_name})

# Tag users
tag_and_users = {'name':tag_name, 'users': [{'email': 'abc@example.com'}, {'email': 'def@example.com'}]}
tagged_user_response = requests.post(tags_url, auth=(app_id, api_key), headers=headers, data=tag_and_users)
```

Also, feel free to give us a shout in Intercom if you're still having trouble and we can help you there.

Comment: Has this been fixed yet?

Comment: Hai I have problem with creating a event .I am already using the requests. 
import requests
from requests.auth import HTTPBasicAuth
url = "https://api.intercom.io/events/"
data = {'created_at': 1391691571, 'event_name': 'kutoosan',  'user_id': '9877'}
requests.post(url, data = data, auth=HTTPBasicAuth(appid, appkey))

This one is working fine, But I have the problem with passing the metadata. I'm trying in this way :

metadata =  {"a": "1","b": "q" }
data = {'created_at': 1391691571, 'event_name': 'test',  'user_id': '9877', 'metadata': metadata}

Comment: I think you are missing a colon in the `if` condition.